# react website running localhost on vscode

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

i am trying to run this repo on my local machine but i cant can someone help?
https://github.com/lucasjolibois54/erp-gruppen-landingpage.git

i try to run "npm run dev" but i get this errors
⨯ ../../node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[8].use[1]!../../node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[6].oneOf[8].use[2]!./styles/Home.module.css
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'

Comment: Did you run `npm i`? if so, make sure the repo is compatible with your machine's node version

Answer (score 0):

Delete package-lock.json/yarn.lock and node modules, install node 14 (you can use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to manage and switch node versions easily) and install dependencies again.

Update:

The project uses `react: "17.0.2` and `"react-animated-cursor": "^2.2.0"` which depends on `react@"^18.2.0"`. Which causes a conflict when resolving dependencies. (This is what I was able to find from the initial `npm i` output. There could be more incompatible versions)

The most ideal solution would be to upgrade the `react` version which can introduce breaking changes and you will have to do necessary adjustments to your code.

If you just want to try to run the project you could run `npm i --force` which will bypass the peer dependency check but this is not recommended and could lead to unexpected errors or broken behavior down the line.

The reason I mentioned node 14 was I was able to install the dependencies and run the project in using node 14 without using `--force` flag. (I assume that in the npm 6.x.x versions peer dependency check is not enforced)

Comment: can you help me do that?because i deleted the package-lock.json and imported the nvm but i am lost now

Comment: You need to regenerate your `package-lock.json` again by using `npm i --package-lock-only` . I am not sure where OP got the info that you need node 14?

Comment: have you tried to run at your localhost? because i updated react i tried to install the npm install react-animated-cursor@latest and i got a lot of errors and then i tried to npm i --force but still cant compile it